# Display image at point using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an image with a click event handler that captures the location where you clicked.

```
$("#image").click(function(e)
{
    var x = e.pageX - $(this).offset().left;
    var y = e.pageY - $(this).offset().top;
});
```

I want it so that when the image is clicked an image appears at that location on top of the image.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [absolute positioning](http://www.yourhtmlsource.com/stylesheets/csslayout.html#absolutepositioning) and the `top` and `left` CSS attributes to place the image over the co-ordinates you calculate.

If the image you want to position is as below:

```
<img id="move-me" style="position:absolute;display:none;z-index:99" src="/somewhere.jpg"/>
```

Have the following procedure in your code:

```
$('#move-me').css({
   left: x-coord,
   top: y-coord
}).show();
```

The `z-index` property ensures the image is shown overlays all other elements on the page...

Comment: This is superb - thanks.  How do I extend this so that I can have N images at N points?

Comment: You'd have to have a method to relate the image you want to display to the point you click on. You might do this by an image map (http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_map.asp). Capture the `click` event of the image map instead of the actual image, and then show the image you've assigned to that area; and position it using the same method as before.

Comment: Sounds a bit difficult, I might just have 10 images hidden then just remember how many I've put down.  Thanks